# how do I implement the percolate-down function in Heap data structure using nodes?

Tags: java, data-structures, heap

I am creating my max-heap data structure by using nodes to make the binary tree, rather then array.
Now, I want to create a percolate-down function, how should I implement this function? is there any other way but recursion to do the job? I'm trying to use loops but all my tries failed, I hope someone could help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
do {
    var currNode = root
    var maxChild = if (currNode.left.value > currNode.right.value) currNode.left else currNode.right

    if (currNode.value < maxChild.value) {
        val tempValue = currNode.value
        currNode.value = maxChild.value
        maxChild.value = tempValue

        currNode = maxChild
    } else {
        break
    }
} while (true)
```

Recursion is only a different way of thinking about loops (or the other way around).
The same solution in recursive form:

```
def percolateDown(currNode: Node): Unit = {
    val maxChild = if (currNode.left.value > currNode.right.value) currNode.left else currNode.right

    if (currNode.value < maxChild.value) {
        val tempValue = currNode.value
        currNode.value = maxChild.value
        maxChild.value = tempValue

        percolateDown(maxChild)
    }
}

percolateDown(root)
```

Edit: Some more checking is needed to detect when the currNode is a leaf and doesn't have children.

Comment: Thank you very much, but does the while loop work on O(logn)? or O(n)?

Comment: I think both the while loop and the recursive method runs in O(logn), as both will do 1 swap / level at most in the binary tree of the max-heap, and the tree will have logn levels when you put in n values.